# Need solution for casting uniqueresult fetched through jpa to String array

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity, hibernate-annotations

When fetching multiple rows through hibernate I used below logic to read each row entry. Working with Hibernate 4 and Websphere 7

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Object[]> objectList = new ArrayList<Object[]>(query.getResultList());\

for (Object[] record : objectList) {
    String entry1 = (String.valueOf(record[0]));
    String entry2 = (String) record[1];
}
```

Now I am trying fetch one single row. When trying to cast it fails.

```
Object[] result = (Object[])query.uniqueResult();
if(result != null) {
    resultDetails [0] = (String)result[0];
    resultDetails [1] = (String)result[1];
}
```

When trying to set String[] as entity it fails for obvious reasons. String[] cannot be used as entity.

Tried copying the object into the array

```
Object[] result = (Object[])query.uniqueResult();
logger.info(result + " -- Length --> " + result.length);
```

Output for the above 2 statement is **[Ljava.lang.Object;@41a841a8 -- Length --> 2**

Followed statement to copy array which fails

```
String[] resultDetails = Arrays.asList(result).toArray(new String[result.length]);
```

even using copyof it fails
    Arrays.copyOf(result, result.length, String[].class);

Need to understand workaround solution for this. Which works without creating new entity class

**---- Update to the code which works for me as a solution.**

```
  Object[] result = (Object[])query.uniqueResult(); int i = 0;
  quoteOwnerDetails= new String[result.length];
  for(Object obj : result){
     System.out.println(obj);
     quoteOwnerDetails[i] = obj.toString(); i++;
  }
```

I identified the 2nd value was integer due to which the case was failing. Doing toString on the individual values solves it.

Please update if you have any other solution to this beside creating a new Entity class.

Comment: Acewin check my answer man i worked hard on it plz at least check and run it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**---- Updated code which works for me as a solution.**

In most of the case calling toString method works better than checking with instance of and then type casting to String.

```
  Object[] result = (Object[])query.uniqueResult(); int i = 0;
  quoteOwnerDetails= new String[result.length];
  for(Object obj : result){
     System.out.println(obj);
     quoteOwnerDetails[i] = obj.toString(); 
     i++;
  }
```

I identified the 2nd value was integer due to which the casting was failing. Doing toString on the individual values solves it.

The return type for the resultset java is mostly Integer or String both of which allow toString to get the value.

Answer (score 2):

When calling uniqueResult **you are asking for a single object, so no array will be returned**. Your code could be written as:

```
Object result = query.uniqueResult();
if(result instanceof String) {
    resultDetails [0] = (String)result;
}
```

To see how this function returns a single object (and not an array this time) see this [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult%28%29).

Comment: If I understand it correctly uniqueresult means object for the single row. In my case it is coming as object array. I can definitely do a instanceof check and update

Comment: I check object array is coming out just fine.

Comment: As a return value of a hibernate `Query.uniqueResult()` call?

Comment: Would you mind printing the result of `o.getClass()` and `o.getClass().isArray()`? And what is the exact classname of that query object you use?

Comment: [Ljava.lang.Object;@4b1a4b1a -- Length --> 2. I got the issue why cast was failing though. One of the column fetch is integer. From your suggestion I realized I should do something like this ----------for(Object obj : result){
    System.out.println(obj);
    quoteOwnerDetails[i] = obj.toString(); i++;
   } Iterate it in a loop and take obj.toString

Comment: I have upped your answer as I realized gap in my code piece based on your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
   List<Object[]> objectList = new ArrayList<Object[]>(query.getResultList()); //You already have this np

    ArrayList<Object> so = new ArrayList<Object>();     
    for (Object[] row : objectList) {           
        so.add(row[0]);         
    }
    ArrayList<String> ok = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < so.size(); i++) {
        String o = (String) so.get(i);
        ok.add(new String(o)); //if you dont do new String(o), hibernate may cry
    }
```

Voila! This ArrayList `ok` at 0th position got what you want (hopefully).

Comment: I need it with unique result method and without using entity class.

Comment: Up voted your answer. It works well. I realized issue in my code was numeric object in resultset which was not letting me to cast the value. Gergely Bacso's answer is more appropiate as when the result comes it cannot necessarily be String.